# Cordova Admob causing google map rendering "grey" screen in Ionic tabs

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, tabs, cordova-admob

Running ionic tabs.  My maps works fine until I click to another tab and then click back to the map.  When returning to the map tab, most of the map is greyed out with a little bit of the map still appearing in the upper left corner.  If I grab the visible section of the map and drag into the center view I see the visible maps is about 2/3rd of the screen - but the moment I let go the visible part shoots back up to upper left corner - and now all the previously greyed out section is just a blank white.

In addition, if I simply rotate my device from portrait to landscape - the map completely redraws itself correctly.  And then from landscape back to portrait mode and the full maps is showing again.

For the life of me though, I can't get the 'grey' out from happening.

In my apps.js:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    globalGPS() ;
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider )
    {   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?||tel):/);
        // Angular before v1.2 uses $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(...)
    }
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html",
    controller: 'TabsCtrl'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:
  .state('tab.map', {
    url: '/map',
    views: {
      'tab-map': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-map.html',
        controller: 'MapCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

The gps functions take place outside of the state/controllers loaded from a standard javascript file, and when all the gps that same external function sets the map as a global var:
`setMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapBody"), myOptions);`

In my controller is defined:

```
   .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,constants) {
      // runs this code on EVERY return to map tab
      $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){
        if (setMap) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(setMap, "idle", function(){
            google.maps.event.trigger(setMap, "resize");
          }) ;
          // $scope.refreshMap() ;  // see note below
        }
      });

      $scope.refreshMap = function() {
          setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.refreshMap_();
          }, 1);
      };

      $scope.refreshMap_ = function() {
        var div = document.getElementById("mapBody");
          reattachMap(setMap,div);
      };
```

reattachMap() is an external function:

```
function reattachMap(map,div) {
  if (!isDom(div)) {
    return map;
  } else {
    map.set("div", div);
    while(div.parentNode) {
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
      div = div.parentNode;
    }
    return map;
  }
}
```

In place of the google.maps.event.trigger(setMap, "resize"), I tried using reattaching the map div thinking it had been removed from the DOM.  Neither method works or even indicates I am onto the correct fix. In my div's that hold the maps I even hard set width/heigh css values as I had read that fixed some ppl's issues (whereas width/height percentages was causing the problem):

```
  <div id="mapWrapper" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%">
    <div id="mapBody" data-tap-disabled="false"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and

```
#mapBody {
  border:2px solid #4e8cf9;
  text-align:center;
  height:700px;
  width:400px;*/
  flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved the issue.  Turns out when moving away from the map tab to another tab, those other tabs are loading ads by AdMob.  AdMob ads are not a part of the main DOM, they are a sub-view and thus they are persistent.  If you navigate to another tab, the ad stays in the same place on the new tab.  When navigating back to the map tab, the ad follows and somehow interferes with google maps ability to properly display itself.

In my app, the first default view is the map tab which doesn't show ads, so no map issues until user returns to the map tab (...and the persistent AdMob ad followed)

Sooo...i now used the above function to remove the ad from the map view completely.

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,constants) {
      $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){
        // this function will run EVERY time user goes back to this tab
        if (setMap) {  // only attempt to remove ad if 'map' is defined
          removeAd() ;  // global external function
      });
```

Comment: If you use `npm i cordova-admob` you can call `admob.showBannerAd(false, success, fail);`, see https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/showBannerAd, this will not remove the ads, but will hide them, allowing to load it faster when returning to the view that contains ads